# Snakemake fails because it cannot create logs inside a read-only Singularity Container

Tags: python, snakemake, hpc

I am using Snakemake from inside a Singularity container. Because of that, the directory that Snakemake wants to log to cannot be created, and I get an `OSError [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '.snakemake`, more specifically the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/snakemake", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/snakemake/__init__.py", line 2562, in main
    success = snakemake(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/snakemake/__init__.py", line 525, in snakemake
    logger.setup_logfile()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/snakemake/logging.py", line 137, in setup_logfile
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(".snakemake", "log"), exist_ok=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '.snakemake'
```

The Snakefile I am using is inside a Singularity-container (there's no way around that, I am on a hpc and don't have root, also using a `--sandbox`ed container doesn't work), and I call it like this (I've also played around with binding other directories without success):

```
singularity run --bind $(realpath .) --bind ~/container.sif ~/container.sif test_simple --cores 4
```

The test_simple rule is a really simple one that only unzips a gzip, for testing - the problem however lies generally in Snakemake wanting to create the log at `<snakemake_base>/.snakemake/log` (see https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/bd5a9239b2684b57ab0143bb709e77afa1493cdc/snakemake/logging.py#L308), which in my case is inside the container.

It doesn't help to use an overlay `--overlay overlay.img` for some reason, and I've also tried using my own (empty) log-handle (`--log-handler-script ~/loghandler.py`) without any success.

Any ideas on how to circumvent this or disable the logging or write it to somewhere else?

Comment: I don't know what happens in your case, but I use Singularity containers with snakemake inside, and when it runs, the `.snakemake` folder is created inside the current working directory, not in a read-only folder. It might help seeing the container definition file.

Comment: Basic sanity check: do you run the container from a folder in which you have write access?

Comment: Can you write to the logs into `/tmp/` ?

Comment: Or maybe don't run Snakemake in the container (e.g., `conda install -c conda-forge -c bioconda snakemake` doesn't need root).